# Settings Files Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

My project has two settings files. settings.js and settings-dev.js. Both contain a settings object similar to the below:

```
settings: {
    api: 'https://my-api.com'
    supportEmail: 'support@mysite.com',
    mainProducts: [
        {
            id: 'asdasd',
            img: 'https://testsite.com/img1.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 'asdasd',
            img: 'https://testsite.com/img1.jpg'
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible for Webpack to merge these objects at compile time and make them available in a module ie `settings` so that I can call it using something along the lines of:

`import settings from settings`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have modified `webpack` file to access `SETTINGS` variable any where in the code.

Firstly create two separate webpack files for `development` and `production`.
here `webpack.config.js` will act as 'development' webpack configuration and `webpack.production.config.js` will act as 'production' webpack configuration.

**webpack.config.js (development)**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const setting = require('./settings-dev.js');

const environment = 'development';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'SETTINGS': setting[environment]})]
};
```

**webpack.production.config.js (production)**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const setting = require('./settings.js');

const environment = 'production';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'SETTINGS': setting[environment]})]
};
```

Now in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --hot --inline --open"
}
```

In your code you can directly access this `SETTINGS` variable. like this

**app.js**

```
var settings = SETTINGS;
var url = settings.api;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is there a way I can define the settings objects in a separate file? I don't want to clutter my webpack config?

Comment: I have modified the answer. May this will help you.

Comment: My issue with this answer is that the SETTINGS variable will be replace multiple times with the settings object at compile time. My settings object may grow to be a sort of CMS. I feel that this will create bloat. That's why I hoped to have them available as modules.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use virtual modules using [virtual-module-webpack-plugin-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtual-module-webpack-plugin). With this plugin I can compile the required settings based on the environment and then pass them to the plugin and it in turn creates a virtual settings module at the path I specified. See example below:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const VirtualModulePlugin = require('virtual-module-webpack-plugin');

const settingsJSON = Object.assign(
    require('./settings/general_settings.json'),
    require('./settings/development_settings.json')
)

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new VirtualModulePlugin({
            moduleName: 'settings/settings.json',
            contents: JSON.stringify(settingsJSON)
        })
    ],
}
```

**random_file.js**

```
import settings from '../settings/settings.json'

console.log(settings);
```